# Delphi - Fast Report - How to show full page area in preview with the Background, Outline, Toolbar, Thumbnails, etc removed

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-11-alexandria

In my form I would like to to show the report full page area in a preview without the  Background, Outline, Toolbar, Thumbnails. ie. Only display the page area without borders,etc.

Using Delphi 11.1 & Fast Reports VCL 2022.2

```
 {Preview}
 frxPreview1.BackColor:=clBlack;//Used for this example
 frxPreview1.OutlineVisible:=false;
 frxPreview1.ThumbnailVisible:=false;
 frxPreview1.HideScrolls:=true;
 frxPreview1.OutlineTree.Visible:=false;
 {Report}
 {Outline}
 frxReport1.PreviewOptions.OutlineVisible:=false;
 frxReport1.PreviewOptions.OutlineWidth:=0;
 frxReport1.PreviewOptions.OutlineExpand:=false;
```

[image]

In the example below I do not want the black area to show, rather a client aligned page only, what setting am I missing?